# Python Tkinter text editor does not save font to text file

Tags: python-2.7, fonts, tkinter, text-editor, rich-text-editor

Currently, I am working on a GUI text editor with python and tkinter. Thanks to the great people at SO (thank you Rinzler), I have managed to modify the font of the text. However, I am unable to save the font and font size to the `txt` file.
I know that this should be possible as Notepad can modify and save a `txt` file with a specified font.

This is the code to save to a file:

```
def file_saveas():
    filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    if filename is None: # asksaveasfile return `None` if dialog closed with "cancel".
        return
    text2save = str(textPad.get(1.0, END)) # starts from `1.0`, not `0.0`
    filename.write(text2save)
    filename.close()
    print filename
```

This is the code (courtesy of Rinzler) to change the font:

```
def choose_font():
global root, textPad # I hate to use global, but for simplicity

t = Tkinter.Toplevel()
font_name = Tkinter.Label(t, text='Font Name: ')
font_name.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
enter_font = Tkinter.Entry(t)
enter_font.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
font_size = Tkinter.Label(t, text='Font Size: ')
font_size.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
enter_size = Tkinter.Entry(t)
enter_size.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

# associating a lambda with the call to text.config()
# to change the font of text (a Text widget reference)
ok_btn = Tkinter.Button(t, text='Apply Changes',
                   command=lambda: textPad.config(font=(enter_font.get(), 
                   enter_size.get())))
print font
ok_btn.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='nsew')
done = Tkinter.Button(t, text='Get rid of Pushy!', command=t.destroy)
done.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='nsew')
# just to make strechable widgets
# you don't strictly need this
for i in range(2):
    t.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
    t.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
t.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
```

Finally, this is the code that reads the font and other configuration information:

```
font = (fontname, size)
textPad.config(
    borderwidth=0,
    font=font ,
    foreground="green",
    background="black",
    insertbackground="white", # cursor
    selectforeground="blue", # selection
    selectbackground="#008000",
    wrap="word", 
    width=64,
    undo=True, # Tk 8.4
    )
```

I have searched the internet without coming up with any answers as to why the font and text size are not saved. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using python 2.7.7 , Tkinter, and this is being run on Windows 7.

Any help manipulation an rtf file would also be helpful (currently, I see the tags and not the end format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for this in tkinter. You will have to pick a file fomat that supports fonts (rtf, .docx, .html, etc), convert the data in the widget to this format, and then write it to a file.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  However, I tried with rtf format and all of the tags are displayed.  How would I display it in tkinter with the actual formatting?  Also, the format is still not saved when I try to save an RTF file from the editor.

Comment: @PseudonymEnigma: unfortunately, you are going to have to parse the rtf data and reformat it for the text widget. The text widget can't display any rich text formats out of the box.

Comment: Thank you.  I am very new to Tkinter.  Could you please show me how I would do that.

Comment: @PseudonymEnigma: no, I can't, especially in a comment box. This is a very difficult thing to do, though there might be some libraries to help. You're still going to have to do a considerable amount of work yourself.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how come Notepad can modify the font?

Comment: @PseudonymEnigma: because someone took the time to convert what you see in the UI into a format that accepts rich text. It was designed from the beginning to save the text formatting.

Comment: So, even though it may be a pain, the file format still supports it?

Comment: @PseudonymEnigma This time I cannot help. I think you should try to add other features to your text editor, such as a finder or a replacer, and for now forget about saving to a rich format or something like that, which can be hard to do. This is just an advice, but if you want to keep searching for a solution, it's ok, because you learn new things, and that is good :D

Comment: Thank you.  I already have a finder and am improving a feature to print.  Any ideas for extra features would be appreciated and almost certainly acted upon.

Comment: @PseudonymEnigma You could add syntax highlighting or languages support, for example  Python keywords highlighting or something like that. Do you have a repository on Github for your text editor? If not, and you decide to have one, make me know ;)

Answer (score 1):

Notepad can only have a custom font and size for its editor window, it doesn't save it to the file, it just remembers the user's custom settings, and applies them to its window when you use it.

<strike>The tkinter text widget can be horrible to save formatting to another format, I've tried converting it to XML to save to a .docx but I haven't been successful. I have used my own format which is a plain text file with an 'index' of the tkinter Text widget tags at the start and their line&column indexes, then a marker for where the document begins, then the document. This cannot hold images though, and it opens with all the formatting index when you open it in another word processor.</strike>

XML is ideal for opening and saving the tkinter text contents - use an xml parser to open, then wite a recursive function to add text with tags as you go. (If you want rich text, this, like xml, is an iterative format - elements inside elements, so could be done like i'm describing below for xml, but you need to write your own rich text parser)

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

    e = etree.fromstring(string)
    #create an element tree of the xml file
    insert_iter(e)
    #call the recursive insert function
    def insert_iter(element):
      #recursive insert function
      text.insert("end", element.text, tagname)
      #insert the elements text
      for child in element:
        insert_iter(child)
        #iterate through the element's child elements, calling the recursive function for each
        text.insert("end", child.tail, tagname)
        #insert the text after the child element
      text.tag_config(tagname, **attrib)
      #configure the text
```

'attrib' is a dictionary eg. {"foreground":"red", "underline":True} would make the text you insert have red font and black underline,
'tagname' is a random string, and needs to be automatically created by your program

To save the file, make a function to do the reverse. I wouldn't bother with using the xml library for this - as tkinter outputs the correct format, just write it manually, but make sure to escape it

```
    from xml.sax.saxutils import escape

    data = text.dump("1.0", "end")
    print(data[0:500]) # print some of the output just to show how the dump method works
    output = ''
    #get contents of text widget (including all formatting, in order) and create a string to add the output file to
    for line in data:
      if line[0] == "text":
        #add the plain text to the output
        output += escape(line[1])
      elif line[0] == "tagon":
        #add a start xml tag, with attributes for the given tkinter tag
        name = 'font'
        attrib = ""
        tag = #the dictionary you stored in your program when creating this tag
        for key in tag:
          attrib += "%s='%s' "%(key, escape(tag[key]))
        output += "<%s %s>"%(name, attrib)
      elif line[0] == "tagoff":
        #add a closing xml tag
        output += '</%s>'%name
```