# Perl Tk: help me fix highlighting in my text editor

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

So i'm writing a text editor in Perl Tk and I have a subroutine for highlighting, it inserts two highlighted spaces for you to type in.

I'm having 3 problems.

1. I want the cursor to move to the left 1 space when the highlight subroutine is triggered. So that when one inserts a highlighting or underline style the cursor is automatically in between the two spaces and the user can type in that style instantly rather than having to use the left arrowkey. I guess my question is how do I insert a style at the cursor instead of the end of the file.
2. The subroutine's formatting of the text isn't saving properly to the filetype. I'm using .rtf currently.
3. I want to implement a drop down font selection menu that draws from a system font list but i'm unsure how.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
#!/C:/Perl/site/lib
use Tk;
use utf8;
use vars qw/$TOP/;

# Main Window
my $mw = new MainWindow;

#Making a text area
my $txt = $mw -> Scrolled('Text', -width => 50,-scrollbars=>'e') -> pack (), -setgrid => true;

#Declare that there is a menu
my $mbar = $mw -> Menu();
$mw -> configure(-menu => $mbar);

#The Main Buttons
my $file = $mbar -> cascade(-label=>"File", -underline=>0, -tearoff => 0);
my $others = $mbar -> cascade(-label =>"Others", -underline=>0, -tearoff => 0);
my $help = $mbar -> cascade(-label =>"Help", -underline=>0, -tearoff => 0);

## File Menu ##
$file -> command(-label => "New", -underline=>0, 
        -command=>sub { $txt -> delete('1.0','end');} );
$file -> checkbutton(-label =>"Open", -underline => 0,
        -command => [\&openfunction, "Open"]);
$file -> command(-label =>"Save", -underline => 0,
        -command => [\&savefunction, "Save"]);
$file -> separator();
$file -> command(-label =>"Exit", -underline => 1,
        -command => sub { exit } );

## Others Menu ##
my $insert = $others -> cascade(-label =>"Insert", -underline => 0, -tearoff => 0);

        $insert -> command(-label =>"Highlight", 
    -command => [\&highlight, "Highlight"]);
    $insert -> command(-label =>"Underline", 
    -command => [\&underline, "Underline"]);
        $insert -> command(-label =>"Title", 
    -command => [\&bold, "Title"]);
    $insert -> command(-label =>"Stippling", 
    -command => [\&stippling, "Stippling"]);

    $insert -> command(-label =>"Find & Replace", 
    -command => [\&find_replace, "Find & Replace"]);
$insert -> command(-label =>"Name", 
    -command => sub { $txt->insert('end',"Name : Thaddeus Roebuck Badgercock\n");});
$insert -> command(-label =>"Bullet Point", -command=>sub { 
    $txt->insert('end',"⚫\t");});
$insert -> command(-label =>"Email", 
    -command=> sub {$txt->insert('end',"E-Mail :\n");});
$others -> command(-label =>"Insert All", -underline => 7,
    -command => sub { $txt->insert('end',"Name : Thaddeus Roebuck Badgercock
Website : 
E-Mail :");
    });

## Help ##
$help -> command(-label =>"About", -command => sub { 
    $txt->delete('1.0','end');
    $txt->insert('end',
    "About
----------
This is a simple text editor written in Perl Tk. This program is licensed under the GNU Public License and is Free Software.
"); });


## Tags ##
$txt->tag(qw/configure bgstipple  -background black -borderwidth 0
        -bgstipple gray12/);
$txt->tag(qw/configure bold    -font C_bold/);
$txt->tag(qw/configure color1 -background/ => '#a0b7ce');
$txt->tag(qw/configure raised -background white -relief raised/);
$txt->tag(qw/configure sunken -background white -relief sunken/);
$txt->tag(qw/configure underline  -underline on/);

MainLoop; 
sub find_replace {
    $txt->FindAndReplacePopUp;
}

sub stippling {
   $txt->insert('end', '  ', 'bgstipple');
} # end style

sub bold {
    $txt->insert('end', '  ', 'bold');
}

sub highlight {
     $txt->insert('end', '  ', 'color1');
 }

 sub raised {
     $txt->insert('end', '  ', 'raised');
 }

  sub underline {
     $txt->insert('end', '  ', 'underline'); #how do 
 }


sub savefunction {
     my $fileDataToSave=$txt->get("1.0","end"); 
    # Trigger dialog
    $filename = $mw->getSaveFile( -title =>  "Selecting file to Save",
             -defaultextension => '.rtf', -initialdir => '.' );
    # save the file 
    open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die $!;
   print $fh $fileDataToSave;
   close $fh;
}

sub openfunction {
      # function to get file dialog box
     $filename = $mw->getOpenFile( -title => "Selecting file to Load",
     -defaultextension => '.txt', -initialdir => '.' );
     # function to load file into string e.g. if you have use File::Slurp
     open($fh, '<', $filename) or die $!;
     my $file_content = do { local $/; <$fh> };
     close $fh;
    $txt->Contents($file_content)
}

sub menuClicked {
    my ($opt) = @_;
    $mw->messageBox(-message=>"You have clicked $opt.
This function is not implemented yet.");
}

#todo:
#figure out how to package as monolithic executables for various platforms
```

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve] ?

Comment: I believe the current example is reproducible if one has Tk installed

Comment: What is `FindAndReplacePopUp` ?  At this line `$txt->FindAndReplacePopUp`

Comment: There is no support for saving in RTF format tk, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28376584/2173773) question.

Comment: For a nice font dialog, see [Tk::FontDialog](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tk::FontDialog)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the highlight formatting at the current cursor position using:

```
sub highlight {
    $txt->insert('insert', '  ', 'color1');
    $txt->SetCursor( 'insert - 1 chars' ); # <-- moves the cursor back into the 
                                           #     hightlight region
}
```